# Android FAB anchor changing when swapping fragments

Tags: android

I have this weird issue that when I replace a fragment and go back to it using the back stack, the FAB is sometimes showing on the upper left of the screen when I anchored it to bottom | end. Its perfectly anchored to bottom | end when just loaded from the activity. How can I solve this? Thanks in advance.

Edit
There's like a 50% chance that it anchors correctly and 50% that it will not.

I have tried manually setting the gravity of the FAB in the java code using this but still does not work.

```
FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton)view.findViewById(R.id.fab);
        CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams lp = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) fab.getLayoutParams();
        lp.anchorGravity = Gravity.BOTTOM | GravityCompat.END;
        fab.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

Here's my code for the FAB

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.berstek.gradius.fragments.RecordsFragment">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recview_records0"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"></android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add_white"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/container"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Hi. Have you find any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

One solution that works for me is to call RequestLayout of your view (the one that has the Floating action button) in the OnResume:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    getView().post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
           getView().requestLayout();
        });
}
```

On Xamarin Android:

```
public override void OnResume()
{
    base.OnResume();

    this.View.Post(() => this.View.RequestLayout());
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I have added only one string to **CoordinatorLayout** and issue disappeared.

```
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
```

So I can conclude that sometimes the Coordinator layout is not on the full screen and than this misbehaviour comes up.

This is full code of my layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    >

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/accountTransactionList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_add_white_24dp"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/accountTransactionList"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
    />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a Framelayout instead and it shows just fine. But if anyone knows why CoordinatorLayout is having that weird issue, I'd love to hear it.

Here's my code.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/white"
android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
android:orientation="vertical"

tools:context="com.berstek.gradius.fragments.RecordsFragment">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recview_records0"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"></android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_add_white"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end" />
```